# My styles from Pixate-Freestyle not styling my views in rubymotion

Tags: css, rubymotion, pixate

I am a beginner trying to use RubyMotion-PixateFreestyle, I have installed the gem, added the framework to \vendor and i run the simulator. I don't receive any errors but still the css has no effect on my views.

As example just I try adding the pixate freestyle to the timer app coming with rubymotion which is used as an example here: [Pixate-freestyle](https://github.com/Pixate/RubyMotion-PixateFreestyle)

I have followed every step of the instructions, my app builds without errors but my changes to the views doesn't show up.